# Can `R.id.btn_login_submit` be omitted?

Tags: java, android

as follows：

```
Button btnSubmit = findViewById(R.id.btn_login_submit);
btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_login_submit:
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

```
Button btnSubmit = findViewById(R.id.btn_login_submit);
btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

They both worked equally well. Can the `switch` be omitted?
The `btnSubmit` has been `findViewById`. Is switch `getId` repeated?

Comment: Yes, `switch` is unnecessary here as  OnClickListener is registered only for the `btnSubmit` button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can remove switch case it work same because R.id.btn_login_submit is same

But my suggestion is use view binding instead of findViewById

Comment: Thank you for you answer! why use view binding instead of findViewById ? Why is the view binding better than findViewById ? My teacher said use findViewById instead of view binding. I don't understand...@SAVAN JADAV

Comment: New in Android Studio 3.6, view binding gives you the ability to replace findViewById with generated binding objects to simplify code, remove bugs, and avoid all the boilerplate of findViewById.
https://wp-assets.infinum.com/uploads/2020/04/viewbinding-the-new-standard-for-view-interaction-handling-in-android-1.jpeg